# Creating custom basemaps for ArcGIS Enterprise

Tags: arcgis-online, basemap, arcgis-online-basemaps, arcgis-enterprise

All the [technical articles](https://learn.arcgis.com/en/projects/design-and-publish-basemaps/) available are for custom base map creation in AGOL, however if I wanted to author a custom vector basemap (add vector polyline layers of my own into the ESRI world navigation basemap to create a new unique basemap) for use in Enterprise web-maps, could it be done?

Comment: Please include a link to at least one of the technical articles that you refer to.

Comment: You may have lost sight of the purpose of a basemap. It's the canvas on which you present your data. While you can certainly publish a map service with additional features to add *on top of* an existing basemap, you don't generally add those features to the basemap itself. And while you could make a *new* basemap that replaces an existing one, then you need to recreate the source data and the other service content. It all comes down to the figure-ground relationship of feature services and basemap services

Comment: @Vince That's exactly what I am trying to do is make a new basemap,but rather then remake it completely from scratch I'd like to merge it with one of the existing basemaps which is doable (at least according to the articles linked).

Comment: That triple link is unwieldy so I think it would be better to have three dog points with headings from the pages linked instead.

Comment: It seems as if that example has you download the data first. If you've concluded that it is doable, then your Question should show your attempt, not ask if it's possible.

Comment: The example is for Arc Online I'm not sure the process is similar for Enterprise or not and cannot find any articles that say otherwise. So, actually I have neither completed an attempt nor concluded anything.